# Slow content appearing in Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm testing [Flutter for Windows](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) and i noticed that, even with a basic 'HelloWorld' app, the content appears slowly, i have a 1 second blank screen inside the app (see gif below):

[image]

The app is packaged with default command (`flutter build windows`).

How can i improve performance at startup ? Is it possible to show the window when content is ready to display ? Or shall i use a splashscreen (I don't even know if this is possible with windows, and if so how) ?

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i improve performance at startup ?

Flutter for Windows currently only supports debug builds, which among other things means that it's using JIT compilation, not AOT as a release build of a Flutter application would. Slower startup time is one of the downsides of JIT.

> Is it possible to show the window when content is ready to display ?

There is currently no callback hook for when the first frame is drawn, so this would be difficult, if not impossible, to do accurately.

> Or shall i use a splashscreen (I don't even know if this is possible with windows, and if so how) ?

There is no support for splashscreens in Flutter's Windows embedding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i hope that desktop support will get better soon! In your opinion is there anything that could be done to improve the situation, or to get a better user experience at startup?

Comment: Yes, AOT support should improve startup time.